# Changing output console in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

As usual C/C++ code is running with cmd.exe. But can I change cmd to powershell console? I need some specific Unicode symbols that cmd doesn't support

Comment: Try it out. It should work.

Comment: Windows console windows (and `cmd`) actually do support Unicode, just not out of the box -- you need to change the default font and call `SetConsoleOutputCP` in your code to match the encoding you're outputting.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What about when you run outside of Visual Studio? The console subsystem will still open a console window (it doesn't even pass by cmd.exe at all).